# Is this character officially Khan Noonien Singh's son?

Tags: star-trek, the-wrath-of-khan

When researching something else, I came across a couple of articles that claimed that there is ultra rare footage of a child in Star Trek II: Wrath of Khan, purportedly claimed to be Khan's son.

[Kinja.com article with pictures](https://observationdeck.kinja.com/holy-crap-khan-had-a-baby-son-1728117002)

[Archive.org snapshot of birthmoviesdeath](https://web.archive.org/web/20150531064751/http://birthmoviesdeath.com/2012/06/12/the-baby-that-was-cut-out-of-star-trek-ii-the-wrath-of-khan)

Pictures from the Kinja article:

[image]

[image]

(The articles state that the second still next to the Genesis device was just before detonation and death, so understandable why that would be cut).

However, is there an official word on if this was intended to actually be Khan's son, or is this just a random child of the survivors?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It is a random child according to Nicholas Meyer**

Trek Historian John Tenuto states he spoke with Nicholas Meyer upon discovering an on-set photograph of the 'Khan baby'. Tenuto states that **writer / director Meyer says that the infant was not Khan's**, but shows that Khan's people are capable of reproducing

> **John**: I got a whole slew of new ones [photographs], and I just
>   finished cleaning them and getting them ready and now I'm going to
>   start cataloging them. One of the things that is in here is **the 'Khan
>   baby'.**
>
> **Larry**: Oh! Do you know why it was taken out?
>
> **John**: **Yeah, there had been a magazine many years ago that had published a photograph, a very grainy picture of a baby by the Genesis
>   torpedo**. And the story in the magazine said that basically, [Larry
>   interupts], yeah, but it was a baby by the torpedo this was a baby by
>   the torpedo as it was detonating. **So the idea was, this was Khan's
>   baby, that was sort of what the theme was, right**? So, but you're right
>   Larry, there were babies there.
>
> So,  I have these photographs, and there are pictures of Nicholas
>   Meyer holding this kid, and he looks, he's got the Khan clothes on,
>   you know, it's not exactly Khan's outfit, but it's Khan's people's
>   clothes, you know? And it's a costume for sure. And then the second
>   cameraman is there, he's trying to film this kid crawling by the
>   torpedo as it's going to detonate, right? So, the original idea was
>   that they were going to basically  show a baby, a toddler, by the
>   Genesis torpedo as it explodes. Which would have been horrifically
>   dark. But of course, it's the implication, right? If they have babies
>   on board, they're gonna die on the Reliant.  That's the idea. **So I
>   have all these, these pictures of them trying to film this moment. So
>   *I asked Mr. Meyer about this. So, what happened was, the idea was to
>   show, it's not Khan's kid***.  It was just to show that Khan's people
>   were reproducing.  And he just said the idea just, it didn't work. The
>   idea didn't work. The moment didn't work."

Source: http://trek.fm/the-ready-room/80 - 2 hours 22 minutes into the podcast

Comment: Good point @Thunderforge - I was in a hurry to get this in after finding the podcast and conversation. I'll get on that

Comment: @NKCampbell : You were wise to hurry, as you had ninja'ed me to this. ;-)  Good job.